# printing solution

Tags: java, pdf, printing, flex4, itext

I have an application that uses Flex (SDK 4.5.1) on the client side and Java on the server. User of this application needs to be able to print documents that have the following characteristics:

- text is in unicode since it needs to support various languages, including Indian languages
- text has embedded images... one can think of this as sequence of span and img elements in a paragraph
- the print layout is in the form of tables and potentially nested tables

I struggled with FlexPrintJob for many days but the result is unacceptable. When RichText's TextFlow has embedded images, it causes all sorts of issues, including missing images, application throwing error, etc.
The following link has the entre discussion:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/3958654#3958654

Then I tried iText to generate PDF and in most parts it works with English. But I need to make it work with Indian languages and iText doesn't support ligatures for Indian languages.

I have tried these 2 options that I know of and neither of them succeeded for my requirements.

Any suggestions on how I can generate a printable document with the characteristics mentioned above using Java on the server?

Any suggestions, direction is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that [JasperReports](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) fulfill all of your requirements. However, it takes some time to get started with.

Comment: Thanks! Any experience with XLS-FO? That also seems to be a potential solution to this problem and it may be easier to implement.

Comment: Back in the years I fiddled around with XSL-FO (using perl, not Java). It's great, but can be very demanding for more complex reports.

I don't know much about XSL-FO transformation in Java (maybe [Xalan](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/index.html)), therefore I can't say which solution is easier to implement.